# How to add css class in return in span tag

Tags: php, yii2, badge

I want to add span tag in return with CSS class Gridview in yii2

I have added span tag and class but it did not work

```
[

    'value' => function ($data) {
        if($data->ispaid==true) {
            return '<span class="badge bg-green">' . 'Paid' . '</span>';
        }
        else {
             return 'Unpaid';
        }
    }
],
```

Comment: Can you expand on "did not work"? Is the code above returning what you expected it to, but the tag is not being acted upon, or does the code just not return what you need? Why have you split that line into three separate concatenated strings when you could just return it as a single string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GridView column sanitizes value from HTML tags by default. If you want to change that behavior you should configure [format](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn#$format-detail) of your column to 'raw'. For example:

```
[
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($data) {
        if($data->ispaid==true) {
            return '<span class="badge bg-green">' . 'Paid' . '</span>';
        } else {
            return 'Unpaid';
        }
    }
],
```